# Ativar página PHP com jquery

Tags: jquery

Pegamos um sistema do qual todas as páginas são em HTML. Só que o cliente deseja que cada pessoa que acessar seu site, as informações como IP, data e hora fossem armazenadas em um banco de dados. Sobre o armazenamento tudo certo, só que como poderia fazer para que ao acessar o site, o jquery ativasse a página em PHP que faz esse cadastro? Se tivermos que trocar o index.html pelo index.php, daria mais trabalho, pois o site dele tem várias páginas e teríamos que mudar o link em todas.

Comment: Ajax resolve, não? Poderia injetar um Ajax que requisitaria um PHP unico que faria isso.

Comment: Olá Guilherme, resolve sim. Você poderia me dar um exemplo? pois não conheço muito Ajax.

Comment: Fox, veja se consegue entender a resposta

Answer (score 1):

Segundo [esse site](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) essa função em jquery executa algum comando ao carregar uma página

```
// A $( document ).ready() block.
$( document ).ready(function() {
   console.log( "ready!" );
});
```

E segundo [esse outro site](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) essa função envia um POST:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: url,
   data: data,
   success: success,
   dataType: dataType
});
```

Juntando as duas ideias acima, de forma bem simplificada:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   // manda a requisição para o PHP aqui.   
   $.post( "paginaQueSalvaDadosNoBanco.php", { ip: "192.168.1.1", hora: "02:00" } );
});
```

Pronto, colocando isso no teu index.html resolve o problema :D

Answer (score 0):

Crie um arquivo chamado `log.js` ou qualquer coisa assim e coloque na "raiz" da pasta publica (`public_html` ou `www`, depende do teu sistema)

Depois crie um arquivo chamado `log.php` também na raiz

Agora no `log.js` adicione isto:

> nota: `(new Date().getTime())` é somente para evitar cache

```
(function (d) {

    function trigger() {
        var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();

        //Defina como true
        oReq.open("GET", "/log.php?_=" + (new Date().getTime()), true);

        //Envia a requisição, mas a resposta fica sendo aguardada em Background
        oReq.send(null);
    }

    //Verifica se a página já foi carregada
    if (/^(interactive|complete)$/i.test(d.readyState)) {
        trigger();
    } else {
        d.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', trigger);
    }

})(document);
```

No `log.php` adicione a suas instruções mysql:

```
<?php

//Conecta
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "usuario", "senha", "banco");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Erro de conexão: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit;
}

$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

$result = $mysqli->query('INSERT INTO `logs` (`data`, `ip`) VALUES (now(), \'' . $ip . '\')');

if ($result) {
    $result->close();
}

$mysqli->close();
```

Agora em todas páginas HTML adicione

```
<script src="/log.js"></script>
```